# Solr: Which size should a synonym file not exceed?

Tags: indexing, time, solr, hierarchical, synonym

Has anybody experiences with great synonym files for the SynonymFilterFactory? We want to write down functional requirements for a new project (group the search results by facets with hierarchical synonyms) without own experiences.

How will be the index time increase per document? Which is a common file size for synonym files and which size should such a file not exceed?

Comment: It depends. You're probably better off experimenting with what you need, and see if using a synonym filter is performant enough.

Comment: you can also split your synonym file into multiple files and apply several synonymfilters in a chain.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll be pleasantly surprised, Solr can handle some decent sized lists: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3233

That said, the only way to know if your particular use case will behave according to your particular requirements is to test it.

One thing though, if you're using configsets stored in Zookeeper (SolrCloud), the max file size in the default ZK config is 1Mb. If your synonym file exceeds that, you'll need to chop it up, not store it in ZK, or [change the `jute.maxbuffer` setting in your ZK config](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/setting-up-an-external-zookeeper-ensemble.html#increasing-the-file-size-limit).